# How can I get the UserId using the new sample code shipping with VS2013 rc in my ASP MVC app.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

I have been using the current version of ASP.NET MVC and have now just started using the version that ships with VS2013 rc.

My code has the following:

```
            exam.CreatedBy = WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
            exam.ModifiedBy = WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
```

From what I can see the latest samples shipping with VS2013 no longer use the WebSecurity DLLs.

With these samples does anyone know how to get the current UserID ?

Comment: Your code is correct. Do you have [InitializeSimpleMembership] attribute on top of controller?

Comment: But the new MVC does not use WebSecurity :-(  It uses another new membership system.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you are using SimpleMembership.

In that case you may try get userID like this:

```
var user = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
var UserID = user.ProviderUserKey;
```

Comment: I am not using Simple Membership. I'm using the new MVC5 membership system.